# I want to know in which format these job templates are stored and it's location in the server?

Tags: templates, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a tenmplate in jenkins using template plugin. I want to know in which format these job templates are stored and it's location in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jenkins job or job template, they are both save its configuration as XML file on Jenkins master/server.

Assume your template or job url is http://jenkins.abc.com/jobs/test,  you can get the XML through http://jenkins.abc.com/jobs/test/config.xml

If you have access to the Jenkins master/server, you can find the `config.xml` on it too.

On Jenkins master/server there is a Environment Variable: `JENKINS_HOME` which point to a directory used to hold all material of job/template etc.

You can print its value via `echo %JENKINS_HOME%` when master/server run on a Windows, otherwise `echo $JENKINS_HOME`.

Then you can find job/template's config.xml from `JENKINS_HOME\jobs\<job/template name>\config.xml`

Below is my `test` job config.xml on Jenkins master/server I run in docker container.
[image]